# How to separate a specific page's comments from other comments

Tags: filters, theme-twenty-eleven

I am using WordPress comments on a page as a Contact form. Comments from my Contact form page are set to auto approve and only visible to the logged admin. Now in the dashboard I would like to separate my Contact form comments from the other comments. I would like to do it either by placing them in a theme option page or by using a filter on the comments page. Why I wanna do this new way? Because I believe it will be more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74035/12615), it was easy.

**Result:**
[image: comments from a single post]

**Code:**
<sub>*check the comments*</sub>

```
// ID of the post/page that we want a separate list of comments
$the_id = '1';

add_action( 'current_screen', 'wpse_73581_exclude_lazy_hook' , 10, 2 );

/**
  * Delay hooking our clauses filter to ensure it's only applied when needed. 
  */
function wpse_73581_exclude_lazy_hook( $screen )
{
    if ( $screen->id != 'edit-comments' )
        return;

    // Check if our Query Var is defined    
    if ( isset( $_GET['hello_world'] ) )
        add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'wpse_73581_list_one_post_comments', 10, 1 );

    add_filter( 'comment_status_links',  'wpse_73581_link_to_hello_world' );
}


/**
 * Only display comments from specific post
 */
function wpse_73581_list_one_post_comments( $clauses )
{
    global $the_id;
    $clauses->query_vars['post_id'] = $the_id;
}

/**
 * Add link to list of comments from specific post with counter
 */
function wpse_73581_link_to_hello_world( $status_links )
{
    global $wpdb, $the_id;

    // Get the number of comments from our post
    $count = count(
            $wpdb->get_results(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                            "SELECT comment_ID FROM $wpdb->comments 
                            WHERE comment_post_ID = $the_id
                            AND comment_approved != 'trash'", 
                            ARRAY_A
                    )
            )
    );

    // Showing our special page
    if ( isset( $_GET['hello_world'] ) )
    {
        // So we can remove the "current" class that is applied to this link
        $status_links['all'] =
                '<a href="edit-comments.php?comment_status=all">'
                . __( 'All' )
                . '</a>';

        // Our link with "current" class and comments count
        $status_links['hello_world'] =
                '<a href="edit-comments.php?comment_status=all&hello_world=1" class="current" style="margin-leff:60px">'
                . __( 'Hello World' )
                . ' <span class="count">('
                . $count
                . ')</a></span>';
    }
    // Showing other comments pages (All, Pending, Approved, etc)
    else
    {
        $status_links['hello_world'] =
                '<a href="edit-comments.php?comment_status=all&hello_world=1" style="margin-leff:60px">'
                . __( 'Hello World' )
                . '  <span class="count">('
                . $count
                . ')</span></a>';
    }

    return $status_links;
}
```